# Casting Objects at runtime

Tags: .net, vb.net, inheritance, casting, abstract-class

Please see the code below:

```
  Public Class Student
    Public Shared Function Factory(ByVal somecriteria As String) As Student
        'Return either a PostGraduate or UnderGraduate based on some criteria
    End Function
End Class

Public Class PostGraduate
    Inherits Student

End Class

Public Class UnderGraduate
    Inherits Student

End Class
```

Say I have some code like this in the app:

```
Dim s as Student = Student.Factory(somecriteria)
```

How would I cast the s variable to either a PostGraduate or Undergraduate at runtime depending on what is returned by Student.StudentFactory?

Comment: You shouldn't need to convert them to a different type of student. Maybe you should be using Interfaces instead?

Comment: depending on what the various differences are, a `StudentType` Property on the base class might also help.

Answer (score -1):

It is difficult to understand what you trying to achieve here but to answer your question you can just use `CType` to convert to the concrete class and `GetType` to determine which type of class it is to start with:

```
Dim s As Student = Student.Factory("")
If s.GetType Is GetType(PostGraduate) Then
    Dim p As PostGraduate = CType(s, PostGraduate)
Else
    Dim u As UnderGraduate = CType(s, UnderGraduate)
End If
```